# Integrate $\int_{\frac{\sqrt{2}}3}^{\frac 23} \frac{dx}{x^5\sqrt{9x^2-1}}$

Tags: calculus, integration

> $$\int_{\frac{\sqrt{2}}3}^{\frac 23} \frac{dx}{x^5\sqrt{9x^2-1}}$$

What I did was trig substitution:
$$x=\frac 13 \sec \theta$$ $$dx=\frac 13 \sec \theta \tan \theta \, d\theta$$

Then my integral becomes $$\int_{\frac 13 \sec\frac{\sqrt{2}}{3}}^{\frac 13 \sec\frac 23} \frac{81}{\sec^4 \theta} \, d\theta$$

But I got stuck here. What can I do next?

Comment: $\frac{1}{\sec^4 t} = \cos^4 t $.

Comment: Use the above and cos(2t) = cos^2(t) - 1 or De Moivre's Theorem if you're feeling fancy!

Answer (score 2):

Use:

$$\frac{1}{\sec^4(x)} = \cos^4(x) = (\cos^2(x))^2 = (\frac{1 + \cos(2x)}{2})^2 = \frac14(1 + 2\cos(2x) + \cos^2(2x)) = \frac14(1 + 2\cos(2x) + \frac{1 + \cos(4x)}{2}) = etc. $$

Answer (score 1):

Substitute $y=3x$
$$I= \int_{\frac{\sqrt{2}}3}^{\frac 23} \frac{1}{x^5\sqrt{9x^2-1}}dx = 81\int^2_{\sqrt2} \frac{1}{y^5\sqrt{y^2-1}}dy
$$
and then apply the reduction formula
$$\int \frac{1}{y^n\sqrt{y^2-1}}dy=I_n=\frac{\sqrt{y^2-1}}{(n-1)y^{n-1}}+\frac{n-2}{n-1}I_{n-2}
$$
to obtain
$$I=81\left( \frac{7\sqrt3-16}{64} +\frac38 \int^2_{\sqrt2} \frac{1}{y\sqrt{y^2-1}}dy\right)=\frac{81}{64}(7\sqrt3-16+2\pi)
$$